# How to make web page/app accessible only from link that is stored on NFC tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating website that will have some valuable content on.

Idea is to make website accessible only trough link that is stored on NFC tag using NXP Tag Writer with "UID Mirror" and "Interaction counter mirror" on.

NXP in their user manual [LINK](https://inspire.nxp.com/tagwriter/tag-writer-user-manual.pdf) on page 3 say :
"Enabling both features will add both UID and counter value as a parameter in link dataset. An example for the link dataset format written on your tag is shown below:

http://www.myhomepage.com?m=unique_tag_UIDxcounter_value

This gives you the number of taps for a particular tag. With both features enabled, backend systems e.g. can check whether a user actually tapped the tag or whether he used the URL from his browser history."

Long story short, UID is constant value and Interaction counter is auto-incrementing binary number. 
Every time new user try to access webpage trough NFC tag link will have different mirror increased binary by one.(Picture1-2)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSTgo.png)
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD6f5.png)

So, how to redirect users that are coming from NFC tag to content site and and users who who are coming from other places to exit site.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your backend language, but basically you get a parameter "m", with 21 ASCII bytes - 14 bytes UID, 1 byte "x", 6 bytes counter.
You break that "m" down into the substrings, and convert to a number.
Then compare the number you got with the last request.

So far, so good.
However, for "valuable" content I would advise to go with a more sophisticated IC, as guessing a higher number is easy enough. 
One example would be NTAG 413 DNA, which adds the "SUN" message to the NDEF. This can then be checked whether it matches with UID&Counter or someone was guessing a higher counter value.